# Sage 50 / C# ODBC interface - exceptions when reading DateTime column types

Tags: c#, odbc

I've been trying to read data from Sage 50 using C# (dotnet 4.0) using their ODBC driver and System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection. Example below (using a much simplified SELECT statement and processing):

```
using (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection("Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=False;DSN=SageLine50v20;uid=*****;pwd=*****;"))                    
{
    conn.Open();

    using (OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand("SELECT USAGE_NUMBER, RECORD_CREATE_DATE, RECORD_MODIFY_DATE from AUDIT_USAGE"))
    {
        command.Connection = conn;
        using (OdbcDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                string usageNumber = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("USAGE_NUMBER"));
                DateTime created = reader.GetDate(reader.GetOrdinal("RECORD_CREATE_DATE"));
                DateTime modified = reader.GetDate(reader.GetOrdinal("RECORD_MODIFY_DATE"));

                // a bunch of other stuff here
            }
        }
    }

    conn.Close();
}
```

For the most part, these sorts of queries are running fine. The Sage ODBC driver is a bit rough and ready and a number of SQL operations just don't work, but sticking to basic SELECT statements yields expected results, except it seems when dealing with date/time values.

If I look at the schema table (`reader.GetSchemaTable()`) it does report that fields such as RECORD_CREATE_DATE and RECORD_MODIFY_DATE are indeed DateTimes, but a number of rows in this table (AUDIT_USAGE) and others which also have these column report errors, for example:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataReader.GetDate(Int32 i)
```

or

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Year, Month, and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime.
   at System.DateTime.DateToTicks(Int32 year, Int32 month, Int32 day)
   at System.DateTime..ctor(Int32 year, Int32 month, Int32 day)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbBuffer.ReadDate(Int32 offset)
```

If I try to analyse the data read in these columns a bit more closely, using `reader.GetChars(...)` to read the character data coming back in these cases instead of the value being returned that dotnet is trying to cast as a DateTime, I indeed find that seemingly nonsense values are being returned, and what's more, they seem to be almost random. If I filter on a particular "problem" row, one time I might get back something like "00000000", another time "-334828473" and so on - none of which are compatible with ODBC date/time formats and so understandably dotnet is failing.

Sometimes if I try to `GetChars` or do other seemingly innocuous operations, my test app (currently just WinForms) simply dies - I'm running it via the VS debugger, and it just stops running and exits the debugger - no exception thrown or anything! I assume this is an exception thrown by the Sage driver but not captured by Visual Studio debugger... I think I've even seen a memory access exception (attempted to read inaccessible memory?) although I don't have a copy of that exception to hand and can't recreate it again at the moment. If I can I'll add the details to this question.

Right now, I'm able to get around this by a try-catch on the `reader.GetDate(...)` calls, catching on InvalidCastException and ArgumentOutOfRangeException. But it's not ideal. I've even seen valid dates coming back in some cases but with nonsensical values (e.g. dates several years in the future) - presumably again nonsense being returned by the driver?

To the best of my knowledge the data in the Sage db isn't corrupted in any way... my theory is that these "problem" rows have some sort of defaulted value internally in the Sage DB that isn't translating well via their provided ODBC driver. Other rows return fine (and return valid ODBC datetime formats when I analyse then with `GetChars(...)`).

Has anyone encountered similar issues trying to read data like this via the Sage ODBC driver and knows of a better way to handle this? Or a better suggestion on how to get that data? The Sage SDK isn't a preferable option, due to it's cost implication and as it's intended for read/write operations, whereas the ODBC link "should" be fine for read-only operations. Anyone who's tried to deal with Sage Support knows what a dead loss they are...

Comment: But this column is Date or a TimeStamp?

Comment: @Oscar, GetSchemaTable reveals that it's mapped as a DateTime in dotnet. My understanding is the Sage 50 database, internally, is a proprietary design so may or may not have it's own internal concepts such as DateTime or Timestamp. Either way, it's identified as a DateTime in ODBC, yet is passing across char sequences that are incompatible with that data type.